# Using grep to only obtain first match in EACH file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a bunch of output files labelled `file1.out`, `file2.out`, `file3.out`, ...,`fileN.out`.

All of these files have multiple instances of a string in them called "keystring". However, only the first instance of "keystring" is meaningful to me. The other lines are not required.

When I do
`grep 'keystring' *.out`
I reach all files, and they output every instance of `keystring`.

When I do `grep -m1 'keystring' *.out` I only get the instance when `file1.out` has keystring.

I want to extract the line where keystring appears FIRST in all these output files. How can I pull this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/keystring/ {print FILENAME ":", $0; nextfile}' *.out
```

`nextfile` will move to next file as soon as it has printed first match from current file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find -exec` like so:

`find . -name '*.out' -exec grep -m1 'keystring' {} \;`

**SEE ALSO:**
[GNU `find` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)